# get how many numbers are in the input list are in the given range

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
givenRange:: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
```

and I want to implement `givenRange low hi xs` so it returns the number of values in `xs` that between `low` and `hi`, inclusive.

For example:

```
givenRange 2 4 [1,2,3,4,5] == 3  -- 2, 3, 4
givenRange 5 7 [1,2,3] == 0
```

Comment: Great function! What did you try?

Comment: What if there are multiple number in the given range? How do you distinguish between "I found no number in the range" and "The number 0 is in the range"? Better to have the type `Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]`

Comment: @chepner: I think the function should return the *number* of numbers in the range.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Hint: write a helper function `countWhere :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int` such that `countWhere f xs` returns the number of elements `x` in `xs` for which `f x` is true. Then use `countWhere` to implement `givenRange`.

Comment: With `filter` the question sounds clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter (\x -> x >= low && x <= hi) xs
```

gives you the numbers in range. Then take the length.

Answer (score 0):

This was not simple. The concept of a range within a range is, I think, best handled with equality testing (==). The range within the range is best produced with the `take.drop` pair. If the two don't match then `0`. There can be no possibility of `0` matches. I tested with 0 5 [5..12], 9 13 [5..12] and more. It seems robust. What cannot be assumed that any range is totally sequential. Equality (==) is the fastest way to check each element.

```
gr s e ls = if [s..e] == (take lls.drop (s-(ls!!0)) $ ls)
            then lls 
            else 0 
      where lls = length [s..e]
```